# New errors after installation of fabric plugin in eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-luna, crashlytics

I use eclipse LUNA for android development. I installed Fabric plugin to add crashanalytics today and suddenly I am seeing some error which I am not able to identify.

The project shows red mark for errors but none of the files have the same error mark

And when I try to run/build the project I get the following error

> An internal error occurred during: "Running GTM diagnose".
>   com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.XmlContext: method (Lcom/android/tools/lint/client/api/LintDriver;Lcom/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Project;Lcom/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Project;Ljava/io/File;Lcom/android/resources/ResourceFolderType;)V not found

Also i am seeing this error repeatedly in the console

> [2014-12-05 08:56:41 - com-crashlytics-sdk-android_answers] Unable to resolve target 'android-21'
>   [2014-12-05 08:56:41 - com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics] Unable to resolve target 'android-21'

This is my first android project so sorry if this is a noob question. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The 'android-21' target issue is likely because you don't have the Android 5.0 (SDK level 21) packages installed. You can install them from the SDK manager.

Answer (score 2):

After installing SDK version 21, you will have this issue:

You are building your app with a sdkTarget defined in your manifest with a value lower than 21.

Your choices are:
 a) upgrade your project to use: android:targetSdkVersion="21"
OR
 b) change each crashlytics kit's manifest's targetSdkVersion to match your project